# SQL Server: How to get "OUTPUT" from Insert on JAVA?

Tags: java, sql-server-2012, prepared-statement

For some reason, I'm trying to get data from the field that I just inserted. And to be clear: *Nope, I'm not seeking a way to get "Insert ID"*.

For example, I have a table named "Members", and I do inserts like this:

- `INSERT INTO Members (ID, NAME, PHONE, BIRTH, CREATE_DATE) OUTPUT Members.CREATE_DATE VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SeqID, ?, ?, ?, getdate());`

This SQL works good and give me the `CREATE_DATE` that I want in SQL Management.

But my question is: How to get THAT `CREATE_DATE` using JAVA's prepared-statement?

I tried to get that using ResultSet, and it told me "Statement didn't return the ResultSet"

```
        con = ds.getConnection();
        pstmt = con.prepareCall(INSERT);

        pstmt.setString(1, name);
        pstmt.setString(2, phone);
        pstmt.setString(3, birth);

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) System.out.println(rs.getString("CREATE_DATE"));
```

And `registeroutparameter` don't look right too because it is "CREATE_DATE", not a "?". Is there any way that I could get my data from OUTPUT?

Comment: insert operation adds data to db and returns the status. If you want CREATE_DATE, you need to write another SELECT query by passing required parameters to get the CREATE_DATE back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not :

```
pstmt = con.prepareCall(INSERT);
```

You have to use `prepareStatement`:

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT);
```

Also : **Insert is not Select**, instead of `pstmt.executeQuery();` it should `pstmt.executeUpdate();` which return an int and not a ResultSet, so if you want to check if your query success or not you have to use :

```
int s = pstmt.executeUpdate();
if(s > 0){
   //success
}
```

> But my question is: How to get THAT CREATE_DATE using JAVA's
>   prepared-statement?

You have to use two separate statement one for insert and the second for select

Comment: Aw, this is sad. I thought I could get that like Oracle's returning

Answer (score 0):

The prepared statement is compiled server side and the parameters are provided by the client the getdate function is executed server side and not returned to the client.

To get the date client side there are many options :

- write a procedure with output parameters which insert the row and return the date
- compute date client side and send to server
- request the server with select query, but this needs two calls